# How to confirm logstash has processed the logs and fed to ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am a new user to ELK. I am using heka as the log shipping agent to ELK stack. I have configured my Logstash to fetch logs from a path. My logstash looks like this

```
input {
    file {
            path => "/var/log/nds/cmdc/cmdc.audit"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["10.209.26.147:9200"]
                }
       }
```

When i start logstash, following is the output.

```
[root@astroELK logstash]# bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/astro_pdl.conf
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations already loaded with version 2.7.1 - omit version 2.7.0
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind already loaded with version 2.7.1 - omit version 2.7.1-1
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
Pipeline main started
```

I dont see anything in the logs also. How can i make sure that logstash has processed the logs from the correct path. If i start ElasticSearch, i could see the following:

```
[Morg] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Please can someone let me know if there is any issue in my configuration set up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to up your ElasticSearch first. Because ElasticSearch is the database for storing the log and Logstash will push log data there.
    Also you need to make sure that your log is coming to the log file which is configured into the input. I am putting one sample logstash configuration which will help you.

```
input {
file {
    path => "<filePath>"
  }
 }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{index}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

  }
  stdout {
   codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

In the above configuration I am using simple file path as input. In the filter section I am also using default `COMBINEDAPACHELOG`.
    In out put section I am giving the elasticSearch host and port and also creating index dynamically for each day.

After configuring this to your logstash config you need to restart elaslic search first then your logstash with the configuration[`Command logstash -f logstash-simple.conf`].

Then it will push your log to elasticsearch and you can view this log via Kibana UI by creating the index which you set in your configuration like `index-2016.05.16`.

You can also check data in your elastic search by using curl command for that particular index.

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of `file` input plugin is to read file as in `tail -f` command. So check if new lines comes the file. You can add `start_position => beginning` option to your file plugin to start reading from beginning of file.

You can also add `stdout {}` to your output pluging along with elasticsearch which will output the results also to standart output.